# Program stops when inputing a variable

Tags: c, input

This is literally my first lines of code in C, so it's really basic.

The code is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int l, b, ar, pr;

    printf("Enter the length of the rectangle");
    scanf("%d", l);
    
    printf("Enter the breadth of the rectangle");
    scanf("%d", b);

    ar = l * b;
    pr = 2 * (l + b);

    printf("\n Area of Rectangle is: %d", ar);
    printf("\n Perimeter of Rectangle is: %d", pr);

}
```

It starts running properly, outputs "Enter the length of the rectangle", but when I input a number, it just stops and I don't get to input the second value.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to a variable to  the  `scanf` so it can fill it with the input: `scanf("%d", l);`, `scanf("%d", &b);`. OT: Don't use `l` as a variable name as it can be confused with `I` or  `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass *pointers to* the variables to get the values instead of the values in the variables.

You should use unary `&` operators to get pointers like this:

```
scanf("%d", &l);
```

Note that you don't need `&` to read strings because arrays are automatically converted to pointers to the first element (except for some cases, including when used as an operand of unary `&` operator).

```
char str[10];
scanf("%9s", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int l, b, ar, pr;

    printf("Enter the length of the rectangle");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    
    printf("Enter the breadth of the rectangle");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    ar = l * b;
    pr = 2 * (l + b);

    printf("\n Area of Rectangle is: %d", ar);
    printf("\n Perimeter of Rectangle is: %d", pr);
}
```